Playwright isVisible function is not working
In types.d.ts file the method isVisible() appears below as deprecated.
isVisible(options?: {
    /**
     * @deprecated This option is ignored.
     * [locator.isVisible([options])](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-is-visible) does not wait for
     * the element to become visible and returns immediately.
     */
    timeout?: number; 
})

isVisible() method in my codebase stopped working after an update. It's now showing as deprecated. How can I solve this?
I am checking if an element is visible, and then executing some conditions afterwards
The method I'm using isVisible is not working correctly after an update.
In my page layer, the method calling isVisible is as follows:
async waitForActivationToComplete(){
    const element_button_processed = this.page.locator(locators.activationDateTime);
    while (await element_button_processed.isVisible()){
        await this.navigateToActivationsTab();
        await this.navigateToVersionsTab();
    }     
}


Can you share your code? What do you mean by not working exactly? See also Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? Thanks.

Please also share a sample website you're automating.

Use https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-visible Consider checking the documentation before asking: "This option is ignored. locator.isVisible() does not wait for the element to become visible and returns immediately. If you need to assert that element is visible, prefer expect(locator).toBeVisible() to avoid flakiness. See assertions guide for more details."

The documentation doesn't have the isVisible method here, does this mean it can't be used? is there an alternative?

The .isVisible() method works, it's just that setting a timeout value will be ignored.
So, if you wish to wait for an element to be visible and set a timeout threshold, use the Expect class.
await expect(element_button_processed).toBeVisible({timeout: 5 * 1000})

You can also expect with a Not -> this will wait up to 5 seconds for the element Not to be visible:
await expect(element_button_processed).not.toBeVisible({timeout: 5 * 1000})


I'm using isVisible() method to check if an element is visible, I want to do an assertion after the element disappears. How do I check this condition using toBeVisible() method?

So, first use the first line of code I shown. After the expect will pass - you will know that the element is visible. Later, use my 2nd line of code. After that code will pass - you will know that the element disappeared.
